# Ban https access to the full web site but enable it for just one url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, ssl, https

I have an Apache configured to have a full web site working with `ssl` and without `ssl` (only `http`) but I would like to just have `ssl` for example at `https://www.mydomain.com/controller/action/params` where controller is not a directory. In other words, `https://www.mydomain.com/` or `https://www.mydomain.com/*` should not be accessible.

Does anyone know how to accomplish that?

P.S. Right now I'm trying with the following code in a `.htaccess` file, but still no luck.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !controller/action/*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: Off-topic. Apache configuration is *not* programming.

Answer (score 0):

request_uri starts with a '/'. Also you can just use '*' the star in this case means 0 or more '/' characters. It should look more like:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/controller/action/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```